# Count equal date parts of the timestamp column ACROSS the groups by the said column

Tags: sql, count, firebird, firebird2.5

I would like to count duplicate date values. I already know that my field "WHEN" is a timestamp, so I have to cast it to type of date.

my actual query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    u.USERNAME,  
    r."WHEN",
    r.UPDATEINOUT,
    case (r.UPDATEINOUT) when 0 then  0 when 1 then 1 else r.INOUT end INOUT
FROM 
    ATTENDANT r 
LEFT JOIN  
    USERS u ON r.USERID = u.ID 
where 
    u.USERNAME = 'rk' and (r.UPDATEINOUT = 1 or r.UPDATEINOUT = 0 or r.UPDATEINOUT is null)
group by
    r."WHEN",
    INOUT,
    u.USERNAME,
    r.UPDATEINOUT
order by 
    r."WHEN"
```

And this is the result:

```
Username     WHEN             UPDATEINOUT  INOUT

rk  09.04.2018, 14:59:45.000    [null]  0
rk  09.04.2018, 14:59:51.000    [null]  1
rk  11.04.2018, 08:31:02.000    [null]  0
rk  11.04.2018, 12:06:52.000    [null]  1
rk  11.04.2018, 12:10:29.000    [null]  0
rk  11.04.2018, 12:23:09.000    [null]  1
rk  11.04.2018, 12:43:47.000    [null]  0
rk  11.04.2018, 17:07:40.000    [null]  1
```

Now I would like to count the duplicate dates, the result should look like this:

```
Username     WHEN             UPDATEINOUT  INOUT  Count

    rk  09.04.2018, 14:59:45.000    [null]  0       2
    rk  09.04.2018, 14:59:51.000    [null]  1       2
    rk  11.04.2018, 08:31:02.000    [null]  0       6
    rk  11.04.2018, 12:06:52.000    [null]  1       6
    rk  11.04.2018, 12:10:29.000    [null]  0       6
    rk  11.04.2018, 12:23:09.000    [null]  1       6
    rk  11.04.2018, 12:43:47.000    [null]  0       6
    rk  11.04.2018, 17:07:40.000    [null]  1       6
```

When I add

```
count(cast(r."WHEN" as date))
```

then it shows me only one.

Comment: you are getting unique results since you are showing time in addition to date
. You can either remove the time column, and it will get you the aggregation you want, or create a separate table that holds the aggregations count per date (I.e. colums date & count) and join it to your result set based on date column

Comment: What is going on with your `WHEN` column?  Is that actually text, or is this just how timestamps are being rendered for some reason?

Comment: @ Y.S thanks will try your approach @ Tim thats timestamps rendred for unknown reasons.

Comment: Could that `CASE` in the `SELECT` equivalently be `COALESCE(r.UPDATEINOUT, r.INOUT)`?  I'd personally find that a bit clearer, but this is a very minor comment.

Comment: Yes it is, i forgot about it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems there are answers suggesting "what to do" but not trying to explain why the results are like what they are. What is happening.
It seems like the topic starter is being given a fish, not a fishing rod.

> When I add `count(cast(r."WHEN" as date))` then it shows me only one.

This is a bit funny. This line shows novice misconception between natural human language like English, and mathematical sets languages like SQL.

R.Kut reads this his added line as "i want to `count` how many [distinct] values of the `given expression` are there".

But that is not what this command actually means in SQL. In SQL it means "I want to `count` how many **rows** are there, where the `given expression` is not null."

And so there is actually NO DIFFERENCE between `count(cast(r."WHEN" as date))` and `count(r."WHEN")` - those two parameters-expressions are either both `NULL` or both `NOT NULL`. Hence the value of `count` of those equally nullable parameters is equal too.

The very attempt to truncate a value of the parameter of the aggregate function, like if it could alter nullability, is a misconception. I was there too. It takes time to get used what aggregates over mathematical sets really mean, and that you do not reading English when you are reading SQL.

Frankly, you could do just `count (1)` here removing not only the typecast but the column itself - it would still be the same, as those are rows, not values that are being asked to be counted. **Unless** there are rows where `"WHEN" IS NULL` - that would be accounted for by `group by` but not by `count`. **After** you read and think through the next section, come back and toy with http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee09a/7

---

Now, there is another parameter to the `count` function that I kind of mentioned above. It is that "distinct" parameter.

*Remark: One may say `distinct` is a keyword of the SQL language, not a parameter for a function, but de facto, not de jure, it changes the way the function works, so in my perception it is the parameter, in that unusual SQLish way the parameters are often given to functions. Or, another way to reason about this, it may be seen a part of the function name, if to imagine have we two functions to choose from, `count` and `count-distinct`.*

So, the topic starter could had added `count(distinct cast(r."WHEN" as date))` instead, and...

....and see that nothing changed. Because while this time he would really say to the server to count row with not-null (always only not-null!) and `distinct` values - the counting goes **within the group**.

And what those groups are?

```
group by
    r."WHEN",
    INOUT,
    u.USERNAME,
    r.UPDATEINOUT
```

See, across the groups we have rows with distinct time-and-date values of "WHEN". And other columns too, but I am not focusing on them. The thing here is that **within every group** both time and date parts of "WHEN" are kept the same. And "being the same" means "there is one `distinct` value, repeated again and again". And if there is only one `distinct` time-and-date value then the reduced values of only-time or only-date would have the same counts (reducing a value can only make to previously different values equal, but not make previously equal values now different).

---

Granted, in other situations, when the counting is going over columns not included in the group (or when there is not `group by` clause at all), the result may differ. There `count(distinct ...)` might do what the topic starter is expecting it to do.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d65bf/7 - example.

However one has to keep in mind:

- that happens at the expense of the extra sorting and grouping work done by a server, potentially making the query slow or consuming lot of memory
- still it would work **within the group** (just groups then would start to contain different values for the `count`ed columns).
- ....just sometimes the group is the whole query resultset (most simple variant - the whole table), if the programmer did not set it to be different by adding `group by` clause :-D

The code of the example, linked above:

```
create table X(a integer, b integer);

insert into X values (1,1);
insert into X values (1,2);
insert into X values (1,2);

commit;

select count(distinct b) from x group by a
-- Result: 1 row: 2

-- or if the whole table is the group
select count(distinct b) from x 
-- Result: 1 row: 2

-- but if the group includes the counted column
-- then every group would contain EXACTLY ONE
-- row with a not-null distinct value
select count(distinct b) from x group by b
-- Result: 2 rows: 1 and 1
```

---

Here we come to yet another modification to toy with.

```
group by
    cast(r."WHEN" as date),   -- <====
    INOUT,
    u.USERNAME,
    r.UPDATEINOUT
```

Now, this time we are telling the server to assemble the groups, in which only "date" part of "WHEN" is the same, while "time" part might differ.

However....

1. I think not every SQL server supports expressions in `group by` clause.
2. Unless there is an `index` made exactly by that expression, the server would have to do much extra work, probably resorting to natural scan and temporary files grouping, which would make the query heavy and slow.
3. And of course you would HAVE to modify the columns list accordingly.

.

```
SELECT 
    u.USERNAME,  
    cast(r."WHEN" as date),  -- <=== no more raw r."WHEN"
    r.UPDATEINOUT,
```

Because, well, you just cannot have "One True Value" for `WHEN` in the row, if you explicitly asked server to group different values of it.

---

Here you may come to the conclusion, that there is no simple straightforward way to have both groups and across-the-groups aggregates. Or to put it differently, to have two different sets of `group by` in one query (I do not want to mention `UNION` here, mkay?).

You would need ONE set of `group by` criteria for counting rows with the same date part (but maybe different time part), and yet ANOTHER `group by` criteria for picking and rendering groups different by both date-and-time.

In plain and simple SQL 1999 that means you would have to make TWO `select`s to make both groupings one way or another, and here Yogesh's and Gordon's answer kick in.

Like Gordon mentioned in post-99 SQL there came Window Functions which could let you have those criteria sets in one `select`, but they are not available in Firebird 2.x anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could upgrade to Firebird 3.0 and use window functions.

Alternatively, you can use CTEs

```
with t as ( < your query here > )
select t.*, tw.cnt
from t join
     (select cast("WHEN" as date) as wdate, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by cast("WHEN" as date)
     ) tw
     on cast(t."WHEN" as date) = tw.wdate;
```

Comment: Are you certain that the `WHEN` column can even be cast to a date/timestamp?  I'm not.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen According to the question, `WHEN` is timestamp column. The data in the question seems to apply a locale-specific format.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `subquery` :

```
SELECT  u.USERNAME, r."WHEN", r.UPDATEINOUT,
        case (r.UPDATEINOUT) when 0 then  0 when 1 then 1 else r.INOUT end INOUT,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM ATTENDANT r1 
         WHERE cast(r1."WHEN" as date)) = cast(r."WHEN" as date)
        ) as Count
FROM ATTENDANT r LEFT JOIN  
     USERS u 
     ON r.USERID = u.ID 
WHERE u.USERNAME = 'rk' AND 
    (r.UPDATEINOUT = 1 or r.UPDATEINOUT = 0 or r.UPDATEINOUT is null)
GROUP BY r."WHEN", INOUT, u.USERNAME, r.UPDATEINOUT
ORDER BY r."WHEN";
```

Comment: Im getting the following error: Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error

Comment: Ok I removed one bracket and changed alias to foo because count is a reserved keyword. My Sub select looks like: (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATTENDANT r1 WHERE cast(r1."WHEN" as date) = cast(r."WHEN" as date) ) as foo But now it count every date exists in my table

Comment: @R.Kut. . . I don't think this would count every date unless or until something missing with `where` clause in `subquery`.

Comment: But there are other user in my table not only 'rk', so it counts f.e. the '09.04.2018' 47 times